# Minitest ArgumentError when assert_equal two 2D arrays

Tags: ruby, minitest

I have the following [test case](https://github.com/mbigras/liffy_diffy/blob/b3e30d296486d677e2e8ac746b767a571c6d5ccf/test/liffy_diffy/differ_test.rb#L57-L58):

```
def test_primary_key
  big = [['foo','bar@','baz'],
         ['cat','moew@','purr'],
         ['dog','bark@','woof'],
         ['mew', 'two@', 'blue']]

  little = [['foo','bar@','baz'],
            ['dog','moew@','woof'],
            ['dog','bark@','woof']]

  args = { big: big, little: little }
  differ = Differ.new(args)
  # assert_equal [["mew", "two@", "blue"]], differ.diff # ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)
  assert (differ.diff - [["mew", "two@", "blue"]]).empty?
end
```

As shown in the comments when I try to `assert_equal` these two arrays I'm getting an `ArgumentError`

What's going on? I don't understand why I shouldn't be able to assert two arrays are equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned your repo and found the problem.

First of all, that's not a issue with `assert_equal`.

The problem is you're setting an `attr_reader` called `:diff` and Minitest has method called [`diff`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest/Assertions.html#method-i-diff) too. That's causing the conflict.

Try changing you code to something like this:

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'csv'

class DifferTest < Minitest::Test
  include LiffyDiffy
  attr_reader :big, :little, :args, :diff_test, :headers, :differ
  def setup
    @big = [['foo','bar','baz'],
                  ['cat','moew','purr'],
                  ['dog','bark','woof'],
                  ['snake','slurp','slither']]
    @little = [['foo','bar','baz'],
                     ['dog','bark','woof'],
                     ['snake','slurp','slither']]
    @args = {big: big, little: little}
    @diff_test = [['cat','moew','purr']]
    @headers = ['foo','bar','baz']
    @differ = Differ.new(args)

    assert_equal [["mew", "two@", "blue"]], differ.diff
    assert (differ.diff - [["mew", "two@", "blue"]]).empty?

  end

  def test_interface
    interface = {diff: diff_test, headers: headers}
    assert_equal interface, differ.interface
  end

  def test_differ
    assert Differ.new(big: big, little: little)
  end

  def test_diff
    assert_equal diff_test, differ.diff
  end

  def test_headers
    assert_equal headers, differ.headers
  end

end
```

It's throwing the correct error now (test failure):

```
 FAIL["test_differ", DifferTest, 0.002584386000307859]
 test_differ#DifferTest (0.00s)
        --- expected
        +++ actual
        @@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
         [
           [
        -    "mew",
        -    "two@",
        -    "blue"
        +    "cat",
        +    "moew",
        +    "purr"
           ]
         ]
        /data/ruby/liffy_diffy/test/liffy_diffy/differ_test.rb:20:in `setup'
```

Comment: You're welcome. Here, line 14: https://github.com/mbigras/liffy_diffy/blob/b3e30d296486d677e2e8ac746b767a571c6d5ccf/lib/liffy_diffy/differ.rb . That receives no argument (that was causing the error).

Comment: You mean an instance method `Differ#diff`? Also then do I need to rename the `headers` reader also to `header_test`?

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. Minitest has a [`diff`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest/Assertions.html#method-i-diff) method.

Comment: Your `diff` method is encapsulated into the `Differ` class. Not a problem. The conflict is with minitest method with the same name. I edited my answer. Hope it helps.